# Не получается добавить нужную запись в бд

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Футболист забивает гол и в базу данных идёт такой запрос. Если футболист есть в базе ему добавляется goal+1. Если его нет в таблице, то создаётся новая запись. В общем мне нужно, если у футболиста меняется клуб, то есть team_id, то создавалась новая запись
Вот структура таблицы:

```
`goals` (`id`, `id_player`, `team_id`, `goal`, `game`)
```

```
INSERT INTO `r_goals` 
set 
  `id_player` = '1', 
  `goal` = `goal` + '1', 
  `team_id` = '1' ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE 
  `goal` = `goal` + '1', 
  `id_player` = '1', 
  `team_id` = '1'
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Соответствующий композитный уникальный индекс и `INSERT .. ODKU`. *Вот структура таблицы:* Это - хрень. Структура таблицы - это то, что выводит `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;`

Answer (score 0):

Условия обновления или добавления данных решайте на уровне вашего приложения. Средствами MySQL эту задачу не решить.